# How to prevent Windows from attempting to save every desktop file operation to a network share

Tags: windows, performance, process, desktop, shared-folders

I have a Windows machine that - for some reason - is attempting to perform a file operation on a network share every time I perform one. If I drag a folder across my desktop, refresh it, anything - it performs the operation on the file share.

The trouble is, this file share no longer exists, so it takes a few seconds before that times out. I found these in the `procmon` logs.

```
1:41:15.5600753 AM  Explorer.EXE    6688    RegQueryKey HKCU\Software\Classes   SUCCESS Query: HandleTags, HandleTags: 0x0
1:41:15.5600968 AM  Explorer.EXE    6688    RegQueryKey HKCU\Software\Classes   SUCCESS Query: HandleTags, HandleTags: 0x0
1:41:15.5601230 AM  Explorer.EXE    6688    RegOpenKey  HKCU\Software\Classes\CLSID\{FBF23B40-E3F0-101B-8488-00AA003E56F8}\Instance NAME NOT FOUND  Desired Access: Read
1:41:15.5601580 AM  Explorer.EXE    6688    RegOpenKey  HKCR\CLSID\{FBF23B40-E3F0-101B-8488-00AA003E56F8}\Instance  NAME NOT FOUND  Desired Access: Read
1:41:15.5602065 AM  Explorer.EXE    6688    CreateFile  C:\Windows\Installer\{F9BAFE88-3436-4235-B22D-5D77F121BB1C}\DD.ico  SUCCESS Desired Access: Generic Read, Disposition: Open, Options: Synchronous IO Non-Alert, Non-Directory File, Random Access, Attributes: N, ShareMode: Read, AllocationSize: n/a, OpenResult: Opened
1:41:15.5602163 AM  Explorer.EXE    6688    RegQueryKey HKCU\Software\Classes   SUCCESS Query: Name
1:41:15.5602333 AM  Explorer.EXE    6688    CreateFile  C:\Windows\CSC\v2.0.6\namespace\jakku   NAME NOT FOUND  Desired Access: Read EA, Write EA, Read Attributes, Write Attributes, Delete, Read Control, Synchronize, Disposition: Open, Options: Synchronous IO Non-Alert, Attributes: n/a, ShareMode: Read, Write, Delete, AllocationSize: n/a
1:41:15.5602583 AM  Explorer.EXE    6688    RegQueryKey HKCU\Software\Classes   SUCCESS Query: HandleTags, HandleTags: 0x0
1:41:15.5602666 AM  Explorer.EXE    6688    CreateFile  C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steam\games\777a52ed6ab637309e25ed929c1257c1fa02cd9c.ico   SUCCESS Desired Access: Read Attributes, Disposition: Open, Options: Open Reparse Point, Attributes: n/a, ShareMode: Read, Write, Delete, AllocationSize: n/a, OpenResult: Opened
1:41:15.5602763 AM  Explorer.EXE    6688    RegQueryKey HKCU\Software\Classes   SUCCESS Query: HandleTags, HandleTags: 0x0
1:41:15.5602861 AM  Explorer.EXE    6688    ReadFile    C:\Windows\Installer\{F9BAFE88-3436-4235-B22D-5D77F121BB1C}\DD.ico  SUCCESS Offset: 0, Length: 12, Priority: Normal
1:41:15.5602976 AM  Explorer.EXE    6688    RegOpenKey  HKCU\Software\Classes\CLSID\{FBF23B40-E3F0-101B-8488-00AA003E56F8}\Instance NAME NOT FOUND  Desired Access: Read
1:41:15.5603173 AM  Explorer.EXE    6688    QueryBasicInformationFile   C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steam\games\777a52ed6ab637309e25ed929c1257c1fa02cd9c.ico   SUCCESS CreationTime: 11/18/2019 3:01:49 AM, LastAccessTime: 10/15/2021 1:41:15 AM, LastWriteTime: 11/18/2019 3:01:49 AM, ChangeTime: 4/19/2021 4:31:23 AM, FileAttributes: N
1:41:15.5603261 AM  Explorer.EXE    6688    CreateFile  C:\Users\Barry Chapman\Desktop  SUCCESS Desired Access: Read Data/List Directory, Read Attributes, Synchronize, Disposition: Open, Options: Synchronous IO Non-Alert, Attributes: n/a, ShareMode: Read, Write, Delete, AllocationSize: n/a, OpenResult: Opened
1:41:15.5603291 AM  Explorer.EXE    6688    RegOpenKey  HKCR\CLSID\{FBF23B40-E3F0-101B-8488-00AA003E56F8}\Instance  NAME NOT FOUND  Desired Access: Read
1:41:15.5603392 AM  Explorer.EXE    6688    CloseFile   C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steam\games\777a52ed6ab637309e25ed929c1257c1fa02cd9c.ico   SUCCESS 
1:41:15.5603644 AM  Explorer.EXE    6688    RegQueryKey HKCU\Software\Classes   SUCCESS Query: Name
```

There are few instances in there where it says `NAME NOT FOUND` - these are the attempts to perform the operation on the non-existent share drive; the drive was called `jakku`

Where would this be configured? I need to disable this to get some performance back!

Comment: Have you tried to use [offline-file](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/web-hosting/configuring-servers-in-the-windows-web-platform/offline-files-for-shared-configuration) feature?

Comment: @Daemon-5 this is not really an offline file feature, but rather that it is trying to sync my desktop changes to an NFS share